# How to run an application with administrator rights all the time?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, uac

I have a shortcut to an application that I have to run as administrator. There is an option in the properties of this shortcut that this application should be always ran as administrator. Unfortunately I can´t select this check box.

It says that since part of the application is part of Windows it can be ran permanently as administrator.

How do I run it with administrator rights every time?

Comment: WHAT application?

Comment: IBM Jazz Team Server

Comment: I'd suggest you listen to what the OS is telling you.  Unless you can somehow de-integrate the software or somehow it has triggered a false positive, then you can't.  The only other thing you can do is disable UAC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click the shortcut go to properties then in the shortcut tab go to the "advanced" button at the bottom left side of the properties window then click "Run as administrator"

Comment: I know how to do that, but I want to do that permanetnly.